# Error when attempting to create Python GUI using Tkinter: "no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable"

Tags: raspbian, python, display, gui

**Sup,**

- I am simply trying to use **Tkinter** (a Python GUI creator) to create a GUI on my **Raspberry Pi**.
- To start, **I only want a GUI to show up on my screen**. That's it!
- The code DOES work on my PC
- The code does NOT work on my Raspberry Pi

**The entire script looks as follows:** 

(works on my PC, bringing up an empty GUI)

> import Tkinter
>
> root = Tkinter.Tk()
>
> root.mainloop()

Trying to run the program in terminal as follows:

> sudo python GUI.py

Produces the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "GUI.py", line 4, in 
>       root = Tkinter.Tk()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1817, in **init**
>
> self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
>
> _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Does anybody have any idea how I can resolve this issue? The error is produced under all of the following conditions:

- Direct HDMI to computer monitor
- DSI connection to touchscreen LCD
- SSH on computer monitor

For reference, if I type the following into my terminal:

> echo $DISPLAY

An empty string gets printed, so I believe therein lies the problem

The following commands don't work either, which might shed light on the problem:

> sudo apt-get update

> startx

Comment: Why do you need `sudo` ? Are you calling script from ssh ? If yes, try setting `DISPLAY` varible by `export DISPLAY=:0` and then running it. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am indeed running from SSH but I see the exact same error when I directly hardwire the Pi HDMI into a computer monitor and use a USB keyboard.

Comment: I like your idea and I tried it, but now I receive the error: _tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0"

Comment: That's because you're running it without x windows. Log in to raspbian desktop by `startx` and try doing it.

Comment: executing the command "startx" leads to an error as well. I started fresh on a brand new microSD card; everything worked fine until I started installing software packages, although I'm not sure which one led to the problem. If I figure it out I'll post which software package is the culprit!

Comment: Glad to know that you were able to solve the issue. You can add an answer explaining which particular library was causing it and mark it as the right answer.

Comment: I have the same problem. I do it like in this tutorial but it doesnt work https://tutorials-raspberrypi.de/programmieren-lernen-am-raspberry-pi-teil-3-gui-erstellen/

Answer (score 6):

I solved it with these two commands:

```
export DISPLAY=0.0
xhost +
```

Comment: where did you put these commands?

Comment: I run it on raspi terminal

Comment: DId it work? because it does not work on mine

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution. This works for SSH terminal, or crontab:

```
import Tkinter
import sys
import os

if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == '':
    print('no display found. Using :0.0')
    os.environ.__setitem__('DISPLAY', ':0.0')


#create main window
master = Tkinter.Tk()
master.title("tester")
master.geometry("300x100")


#make a label for the window
label1 = Tkinter.Label(master, text='Hellooooo')
# Lay out label
label1.pack()

# Run forever!
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: FYI for python3 one must instead use `import tkinter` and besides this solution leads to an error: `TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0.0"`

Answer (score -3):

you have just to write: export MPLBACKEND="agg"

Comment: Where would the OP add this line? What does it do? Where can they find documentation about this? How is this better/different from the other answer?

Comment: This is only applicable for `matplotlib`.